# mongodb Query to get all results if filter value === 'All' if not get the specified filter

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, filter

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIhZI.png)  [Filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAteu.png)I have 3 filters with different values and the user can choose 'All' option to disable that specific filter i want to know what query should i use working with (mongodb nodejs/expressjs)

Comment: Hi there! Can you show the snippet of code where the the filter is supposed to be used?

Comment: i added two images one for the code and the other is the filters in the front end

Comment: Hi ! This is your first question on stack overflow. Please give you a moment to take a tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Visit the help center to discover how too improve your question and maximise the chance to get help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Welcom on Stack Overflow !